# MIPS: n choose k function

Tags: mips

So I'm currently writing a calculator in MIPS and I'm trying to write an n choose k function. 
The algorithm I want to use is this:

If I want to do 5 choose 3 then I'll have a loop that does (5*4*3)/(3*2*1). Suppose I already have multiply and divide functions, how would I implement this in MIPS?

Right now I have this, but it isn't working at all:

```
calnchoosek:
    move $t1, $a0
    move $t2, $a2

    move $t3, $a0 # copies for the counter
    move $t4, $a2

loop_top:
    beq $t3, $t4, loop_bottom
    subi $t3, $t3, 1

    move $a0, $t1
    move $a2, $t3
    jal multi
    move $t1, $v0

    j loop_top

loop_bottom:
    beq $t4, $zero, exit1
    subi $t4, $t4, 1

    move $a0, $t2
    move $a2, $t4
    jal multi
    move $t2, $v0

    j loop_bottom

exit1:
    move $a0, $t1
    move $a2, $t2
    jal divi
```

I'm thinking my logic is totally flawed and I might have to start fresh. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `loop_bottom`, `$t4` will be set to 0 in the last iteration. Multiply `$t2` by zero and get zero for your denominator. `divi` is calculating K*(N!-K!)/0 – you divided by zero!

Comment: Whoops... Thanks for the heads up!